# How to make a file downloadig directely without open it in browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this:

```
<a href="localhost/pdf/data.pdf"> Download this </a>
```

and when i click on this in the browser the file opened.I need to make this download directly without open it.Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="localhost/pdf/data.pdf" download> Download this </a>
```

to find this answer you just can use google by the way and don't need to open a new question

Answer (score 1):

You can use the download attribute

```
<a href="localhost/pdf/data.pdf" download> Download this </a>
```